# getting invalid csp policy - must be array, string, or plain object when deploying node.js application on centos

Tags: node.js, express, centos

We have been running our Node.js application on centOS for the past few months. Lately we are getting this error on deployment intermittently. What could be the issue?

```
error: uncaughtException: invalid csp policy - must be array, string, or plain object date=Fri May 06 2016 11:07:48 GMT+0530 (IST), pid=5175, uid=0, gid=0, cwd=/, execPath=/usr/local/bin/node, version=v5.10.1, argv=[/usr/local/bin/node, /home/ubuntu/xxxxxx/server.js], rss=83447808, heapTotal=63200032, heapUsed=40600280, loadavg=[1.04150390625, 0.81201171875, 0.5048828125], uptime=565, trace=[column=null, file=null, function=Error, line=null, method=null, native=true, column=11, file=/home/ubuntu/xxxxxx/node_modules/lusca/lib/csp.js, function=module.exports.createPolicyString, line=60, method=exports.createPolicyString, native=false, column=13, file=/home/ubuntu/xxxxxx/node_modules/lusca/lib/csp.js, function=Function.module.exports [as csp], line=23, method=module.exports [as csp], native=false, column=40, file=/home/ubuntu/xxxxxx/node_modules/lusca/index.js, function=null, line=33, method=null, native=false, column=null, file=null, function=Array.forEach, line=null, method=forEach, native=true, column=28, file=/home/ubuntu/xxxxxx/node_modules/lusca/index.js, function=module.exports, line=29, method=exports, native=false, column=9, file=/home/ubuntu/xxxxxx/server.js, function=, line=99, method=null, native=false, column=34, file=module.js, function=Module._compile, line=413, method=_compile, native=false, column=10, file=module.js, function=Object.Module._extensions..js, line=422, method=Module._extensions..js, native=false, column=32, file=module.js, function=Module.load, line=357, method=load, native=false, column=12, file=module.js, function=Function.Module._load, line=314, method=Module._load, native=false, column=10, file=module.js, function=Function.Module.runMain, line=447, method=Module.runMain, native=false, column=18, file=node.js, function=startup, line=146, method=null, native=false, column=3, file=node.js, function=null, line=404, method=null, native=false], stack=[Error: invalid csp policy - must be array, string, or plain object,     at Error (native),     at module.exports.createPolicyString (/home/ubuntu/xxxxxx/node_modules/lusca/lib/csp.js:60:11),     at Function.module.exports [as csp] (/home/ubuntu/xxxxxx/node_modules/lusca/lib/csp.js:23:13),     at /home/ubuntu/xxxxxx/node_modules/lusca/index.js:33:40,     at Array.forEach (native),     at module.exports (/home/ubuntu/xxxxxx/node_modules/lusca/index.js:29:28),     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/xxxxxx/server.js:99:9),     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34),     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10),     at Module.load (module.js:357:32),     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12),     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10),     at startup (node.js:146:18),     at node.js:404:3]
```

our server.js code for the lusca npm is as follows

```
app.use(lusca({
    csrf: false,
    csp: { /* ... */},
    xframe: 'SAMEORIGIN',
    p3p: 'ABCDEF',
    hsts: {maxAge: 31536000, includeSubDomains: true, preload: true},
    xssProtection: true
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with empty csp. Set some value for csp as below

app.use(lusca({
    csrf: false,
    csp: {  policy: {
            'default-src': '\'self\'',
            'img-src': '*' }
          },

or simply the policy for all source:
 csp: {  policy: {'default-src': '*'} },

The detailed example can be found on: https://github.com/krakenjs/lusca.

It worked for me even without the csp policy with older version of lusca(1.3). Might be something changed.